# Session not working on vue+laravel page

Tags: php, laravel, session, vue.js

I am making a web page with `vue single file component`, and `laravel` as `back-end` the page is multi-lenguage, i send the language selected by the user with ajax and save it to the session, so i can `setLocale(session()->get('lang;))` in the AppServiceProvider, i need laravel to return some errors, like authorizations, validations, etc.
The problem is that the session is not being saved.

if i `return session()->get('lang')` in the call where i am saving it, it returns what i am sending.
but  if i `return session()->get('lang')` in my next call to another controller, it returns `null`

i am using the `file driver`, change it to `cookie` but it did not work either.

how can i make the session work?

**As requested**

I am using the laravel mix for copiling vue, as far as i know i am not using any proxy, i am running it on local for now

My routes are on the api file so i guess it uses the api middleware default

```
Route::namespace('Home')->group(function(){
    Route::get('home','HomeController@getIndex');
    Route::get('home/change-lang','LangController@changeLang');

    Route::get('news/{type}','NewsController@getNews');

});
```

The controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Home;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class LangController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function changeLang(Request $request)
    {
        app()->setLocale($request->input('lang'));
        session(['lang' => $request->input('lang')]);
        return response()->json([
            'lang' => app()->getLocale()
        ]);
    }
}

AppServiceProvider

<?php

namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        app()->setLocale(session()->has('lang') ? session()->get('lang') : 'es');
    }
}
```

the route configuration in the front is

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/rdjvzla/public/home/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/rdjvzla/public/home/news/:type',
            name: 'news',
            component: News
        }
    ]
});
```

and i send the request like this

```
this.$axios.get(this.$asset('api/home/change-lang'),{
    params : {
        lang : this.$i18n.locale
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you give more details about your frontend setup? Are you using webpack + a proxy to the backend? Are you using the web or api middleware? Best would be to provide - Route definition, Controller method and frontend setup

Comment: Are you using the `web` middleware? That is the middleware responsible for the session (as I've read on numerous other posts here on SO)